# How can avoid redirect in error code 410 in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a code in .htaccess for giving a 410 error in determinated urls but if the request has https and www works fine nevertheless, when the request has http or is without www then redirect to the page 410.php giving a code 200. I don't know why it does not give always the 410 code error.

https://www.example.com/folder1/file1.php?id=1 -> works fine giving a 410 error
https://example.com/folder1/file1.php?id=1 -> 301 redirect to /410.php and code 200
http://www.example.com/folder1/file1.php?id=1 -> 301 redirect to /410.php and code 200
http://example.com/folder1/file1.php?id=1 -> 301 redirect to /410.php and code 200

This is the code:

```
<Files .htaccess> 
deny from all 
</Files> 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (file1.php|file2.php)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(id)\=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* - [G,NC]

#These rules also works bad, it does the same that in my question
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2)/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(pag|az)\=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* - [G,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.|videos.|css.|js.|images.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]

RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/folder/((.*).htm|file3.php)$ https://www.example.com/folder/

Redirect 410 /Forum
Redirect 410 /forum
Redirect 410 /search/word1

#Redirect to www except folder1 and forder2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|videos|css|js|images)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(/folder1/|/folder2/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example/$1 [L,R=301]

#Redirect to https except folder1 and folder2
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(folder1|folder2)/([0-9]+)-g([0-9]+)/ [NC]
# Include in the next line all folders to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/folder1/|/folder1/)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^fotos/originales/([0-9]+)_1\.jpg$ https://www.example.com/fotos/$1/$1_l.jpg [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fotos/([0-9]+)_1\.jpg$ https://www.example.com/fotos/$1/$1_s.jpg [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/galerias/ [NC]
RewriteRule galerias/([0-9]+)(.*).jpg$ /galerias/$1/$1$2.jpg  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/galerias/ [NC]
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)(.*).jpg$ $1/$1$2.jpg [L]

RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)-g(.*)-xxl(.*)/(.*)$ folder1/index.php?id=$1&g=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder1/([0-9]+)-g(.*)/(.*)$ folder1/index.php?id=$1&g=$2 [L]


#These rules also works bad, it does the same that in my question
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p?orden=[a-z|A-Z] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder2/
RewriteRule .* - [G,L]


#account
RewriteRule ^account/(.*) account/?do=$1 [QSA,L]

#Comunidad /comunidad/?id=1
RewriteRule ^comunidad/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ comunidad/?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^comunidad/temas/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ comunidad/?fid=$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 403 “Not “Available”
ErrorDocument 406 "Not “Available"

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
ErrorDocument 301 "-"

AddType text/html .html .shtml .php

AddType application/javascript js jsonp
AddType application/json json
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: you should redirect non-https and non-www to https-www first.

Comment: The code you posted isn't causing the problem.   What else do you have in your .htaccess file?   And are your `PHP` files doing any redirects?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There are a lot of rules in the htaccess but everything is bellow, the problem happens when it has to redirect to www or https, but these rules have to take the url before and finish, I don't know what is happening, I've emptied the php file and happens the same.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full .htaccess file.  Directives in .htaccess are not strictly executed in order.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I've just added the rest of htaccess. If I delete this line "ErrorDocument 410 /410.php" works without redirection but it shows a default page empty with the error in a line.

Comment: Maybe it's due to the content of your 410.php page. What's in that?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller nothing special at 410.php, a html code with a photo and a searcher box. the problem is with the rules in htaccess, it makes a redirection instead of show up content of 410.php and to throw the 410 code error, when I do the 410 with php works fine, also if I go to a non exist url as mydomain.com/kahdjfd. I'm thinking about something wrong in the server settings